# Paid time off leaves carried forward to next year

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am very new to sharepoint and I am designing a sharepoint based leave balance system for my company. If an employee has accumulating leaves till Dec 31st, it will be carried forward/accumulated to leaves for next year. However if these accumulated leaves aren't used by the end of first quarter of next year, they should be simply discarded.

How can I accomplish this task by Sharepoint?

Comment: @teylyn, I assume that I have to run workflows on the end dates and do the check you specified above. Right?

Comment: The business logic is really your responsibility. I can't tell you which rules you need to apply. If in doubt, ask your HR department what the business rules are.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually:

I assume you have a column for current leave balance. You also need a helper column for carryover and a few workflows for this.

At year end, run a workflow that copies any current leave entitlement from the leave balance column to the carryover helper column.

When leave is taken in the first quarter, subtract it from both the leave balance column and from the carryover column.

At the end of the first quarter run a workflow that looks at the carryover column and if it has a positive number, subtract that from the leave balance column.

The workflows can be created with either SharePoint designer as SP 2013 site workflow that loops through all items in the leave list, or with Microsoft Flow.